# Two file selector dialog in batch (Batch recipe)

Tags: batch-file

I need two files to be selected using batch:

```
@echo off
call :filedialog file
echo selected  file is : "%file%
call :filedialog1 file
echo selected  file is : "%file1%
pause
exit /b


:filedialog :: &file
setlocal 
set dialog="about:<input type=file id=FILE><script>FILE.click();new ActiveXObject
set dialog=%dialog%('Scripting.FileSystemObject').GetStandardStream(1).WriteLine(FILE.value);
set dialog=%dialog%close();resizeTo(0,0);</script>"
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%p in ('mshta.exe %dialog%') do set "file=%%p"
endlocal  & set %1=%file%

:filedialog1 :: &file1
setlocal 
set dialog="about:<input type=file id=FILE><script>FILE.click();new ActiveXObject
set dialog=%dialog%('Scripting.FileSystemObject').GetStandardStream(1).WriteLine(FILE.value);
set dialog=%dialog%close();resizeTo(0,0);</script>"
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%p in ('mshta.exe %dialog%') do set "file=%%p"
endlocal  & set %1=%file1%

START bincmp.exe -patch "%file1% "%file%
```

or

```
    for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%p in ('mshta.exe %dialog%') do set "file=%%p"
    endlocal  & set %1=%file% & set %2=%file1%
```

This is just an example that doesn't work.
For one file works without a problem.

Comment: I tried so too, it doesn't work for me either, I have added an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the same argument to both functions. When you call the function you are telling it to assign the value of the file selected to the variable named file both times. You don't need two separate functions to do this. You just need one and when you are calling that function use a different variable name each time you call the function.

```
@echo off
call :filedialog file1
echo selected  file1 is : "%file1%"
call :filedialog file2
echo selected  file2 is : "%file2%"
START bincmp.exe -patch "%file1%" "%file2%"
pause

exit /b


:filedialog var -- returns variable to passed reference variable
setlocal 
set dialog="about:<input type=file id=FILE><script>FILE.click();new ActiveXObject
set dialog=%dialog%('Scripting.FileSystemObject').GetStandardStream(1).WriteLine(FILE.value);
set dialog=%dialog%close();resizeTo(0,0);</script>"
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%p in ('mshta.exe %dialog%') do set "file=%%p"
endlocal  & set "%1=%file%"
goto :EOF
```